# Why doesn't it restore first activity's layout when back pressed second activity in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, layout

Why doesn't it restore the first `Activity's` layout when back button is pressed in the second `Activity`?

First Activity below:

```
public class ProdutosListActivity extends ListActivity 
    implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String[] de = {"imagem_produto", "nome_produto", "peso","preco", "tipo_produto"};
        int[] para = {R.id.imagem_produto, R.id.nome_produto, R.id.peso,R.id.preco, 
                R.id.tipo_produto};
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listarProdutos(), R.layout.produtos_list, de,para);
        adapter.setViewBinder(this);
        setListAdapter(adapter);getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Still First Class

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    this.produtoSelecionada = position;
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Pedidos.class);
    String info =  Integer.toString(position);
    Map<String,Object> map = produtos.get(position);
    intent.putExtra("produto", (java.io.Serializable) map );
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Second Activity

```
public class Pedidos extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pedidos);
    }
```

Implement Group List

```
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {


    if(view.getId() ==  R.id.tipo_produto){
        //if(!tipoProduto.equals(data)){
        if(!listCategoriesProducts.containsKey(data)){

            TextView textView = (TextView) view;
            textView.setText(textRepresentation);
            listCategoriesProducts.put(textRepresentation,data.toString()        );
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return true;
    }
    if(view.getId() == R.id.tipo_produto){
        Integer id = (Integer) data;
        view.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(id));
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: how did you show the second activity add it to the code

Comment: you dont want to restore layout or the activity?

Comment: it seems that you are using `finish()` after starting the `SecondActivity`

Comment: Can you show the code for the click listener?

Comment: Show how you are starting the `Pedidos` activity

Comment: The activity was restored, but layout doesn't.

Comment: The activity was restored, but layout doesn't.

Comment: onCreate must have setContentView(layoutRes); When did you set this?

Comment: I am already using adapter binder , where I pass resourceLatout on method

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method, call `setContentView(R.id.your_view)` again.

Comment: The screen is blank at all or listview is empty?

Comment: Petiscos and Doces, when do you populate / or create these labels?

Comment: I implemented SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder on method setViewValue() to group elements